# Naturally, you don't want to meet me again

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Scream out or scream low 
You will only hear me when I <s>blow</s> whisper 
Stand back or stand front 
You will only see me when I want 
Go there or no-where 
I can be there beside with no distance 
I don't have ticket 
I can't make chitchat 
But once you know what I am 
You don't want to meet me again.

> who or what am I?

---

Hint 1:

> I could be the same shape as you 
>  Or I could be in the other shape you never saw 
>  I was just like you before 
>  May be you were my beloved or more

Hint 2:

> No hint on this because I might be staring right into your face.
>  You know or never know until I show.

Comment: answer might be "terrorist"

Comment: @Nai is it a 'shadow'?

Comment: @RahulBasu kinda, but someone got answer below, I have to check it reasoning whether it is valid to be ticked as correct/right/complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they exist,

> Ghost

Scream out or scream low 
You will only hear me when I blow

> Since they fly, so the one way you can hear it is when they blow maybe make sounds.

Stand back or stand front 
You will only see me when I want

> Ghosts appear on will and when they want you to see them.

Go there or no-where 
I can be there beside with no distance

> They have supreme powers and can appear appear anywhere in no time.

I don't have ticket 
I can't make chitchat 
But once you know what I am 
You don't want to meet me again.

> Yes we don't wish to comeback to you or meet you if we know you are ghost.

I could be the same shape as you 
Or I could be in the other shape you never saw 
I was just like you in before 
May be you were my beloved or more

> Assuming ghost of a human being who might have been close to you. Mostly ghost appear to people whom are their relatives or acquaintances.

No hint on this because I might be staring right into your face.
You know or never know until I show.

> I hope its not true for me. :-)

Comment: Yeah I think this is it too.

Comment: +1 and ticked as Correct answer. "user1717828" got this answer first but reasons wasn't satisfied. This is exactly the answer that I made this riddle. 
*I really like the explanation to my hints :D - I think many Asians (including me) believe there are ghosts really exist.

Comment: @Nai even if many people believe in ghosts, the attributes you're giving them are far from 'accepted'. In many versions of ghosts, they can make plenty of sounds besides 'blowing', they're actively sought out by loved ones, they're bound to certain places (so can't appear anywhere), have little control over their appearance, but are bound to certain times/events, can talk (seances?), can't take your shape (because you're still alive..) etc. Which i think is the problem I and a lot of people have with this riddle/answer, and the reason that another answer has more votes and fits better.

Comment: I guess you are talking right with this riddle, there're too many weakness I created it. but other things about ghosts, I think we (may be other more) have different views - "blow" is just a word I choose, yes that they might be bound to certain but ghost can travel as far as I read, and ghost talk (can see in movie or story), and important thing, ghost can get into your body if there's chance and certain reason (but I think I didn't talk about this in the riddle!?) - I think I should just gave this one as Correct as I was thinking Ghost when making this.

Comment: It's not about the answer, it's about the words I chose and my skills on making this riddle lacks something. Really sorry. @DrunkWolf

Answer (score 6):

Are you a..

> Hurricane

My first go at this so I hope I'm doing it right xD

Edit, a explanation to as why:

> - You can scream all your want, but you'll only hear a hurricane once it's started to get enough "speed" built up, aka **blowing winds**.
>  
>  - You'll only see a hurricane when it is strong enough, "when it wants".
>  
>  - You can go anywhere, and a hurricane can cover enough distance in no time at all to be considered "be there with no distance".
>  
>  - A hurricane can't make chitchat, once it stats to blow things get messy and loud.
>  
>  - And the title says "Naturally" hinting towards a natural object/thing, and a hurricane is the force of nature so there's that.
>  
>  - Oh and ofc you don't want to meet him/her/it again : )

Comment: Hey and welcome to Puzzling.se, While there's nothing wrong with your post or it's content, it's customary to answer riddles like this with a bit more of a breakdown **why** this is your answer. Many prefer a line by line breakdown, in which you mention how each clue pertains to your answer, but a more verbal explanation is acceptable to.

Comment: @DrunkWolf Thank you for explaining the common ways of Puzzling. I'm still not quite convinced my answer is right but I can always hope! : )

Comment: at the very least it's a proper guess, which is all you can ask for. A lot of these questions have multiple answers with varying degrees of completeness. People appreciate a good guess as much as the right one.

Comment: @Torxed thank you for your answer and first try seems really good. But yet not the answer I have in my mind. 
This question is going to be closed soon. I think there's no one more to get the right answer. :'(

Comment: @Nai oh shoot, well thanks for thinking highly of my guess. Oh we'll get the answer soon. It's just a good riddle

Answer (score 3):

Is it a

> ghost?

---

...only see me when I want

> They appear.

I can be there beside with no distance

> They fly.

But once you know what I am \ You don't want to meet me again.

> Because they're scary.

Comment: Seems so obvious now...

Comment: I have ticked @thepace answer as it matchs most of my thinking on this riddle. Ur answer is right, but reasoning didn't satisfied me. Sorry! But +1 for getting right answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1:

> Icy wind

Explanation:

Scream out or scream low
You will only hear me when I blow

> A sufficiently powerful howl of wind will be audible over a scream.

Stand back or stand front
You will only see me when I want

> Wind is invisible, but I guess 'feeling' and 'seeing' could be considered analogous to one another in this case.

Go there or no-where
I can be there beside with no distance

> You can't feel still wind, obviously.

I don't have ticket
I can't make chitchat
But once you know what I am
You don't want to meet me again.

> Who wants to endure another draft of icy wind?

A bit of a long shot on some of the clues, but I think it fits.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, might it be:

> DREAM

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Could you please clarify as to why you think this is the answer?

Comment: This is not the answer I have in my mind. And also lacks of reasoning, pls check how to write to be a good answer. :-) thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 2:

> A bomb going off

Similar to my earlier answer, using multiple meanings of 'blow'.

> Only in this case, a bomb will be concealed and hard to detect, but pretty much obvious when it blows.

Comment: Sorry, this can be even write in comment : )
Not yet the right answer. Thanks for trying out two times. :D

Answer (score 1):

Is it a

> volcano?

---

...only hear me when I blow

> The eruption.

...only see me when I want

> When the volcano "chooses" to erupt.

I can be there beside with no distance

> The tremors from the eruption reach far away.

But once you know what I am \ You don't want to meet me again.

> Because death.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but not the answer I have in my mind, and reasons seem too light to highlight it.
This question is going to be closed soon. I think there's no one more to get the right answer. :'(

Comment: @Nai, Please post answer in comments so we can help you improve next time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a...

> spy / ninja / assasin ?

**Explanation:**

*Scream out or scream low*

*You will only hear me when I blow*

> A spy/ninja will be really stealthy so you can't hear them unless they're breathing loudly, or 'blowing'.

*Stand back or stand front*

*You will only see me when I want*

> The stealth argument applies here too.

*Go there or no-where*

*I can be there beside with no distance*

> Spies/ninjas/assasins are trained to sneak up on people quickly.

*I don't have ticket*

*I can't make chitchat*

> Why would any sane ninja make chitchat?

*But once you know what I am*

*You don't want to meet me again.*

> People generally don't want to meet assasins for coffee?

Now that I've typed all of this, the word *'stalker'* also comes to mind....

Comment: For centain condition, it can be considered as right one. But the answer I have in my mind is for any situation. 
I mean if you know the ninja personally - those sentences cannot happened. Your reason is only for the times that spy/ninja/assasins fight.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> Fear

Explanation:

Scream out or scream low
You will only hear me when I blow

> No matter if you scream or not, the fear is there and you will feel it (when it blows);

Stand back or stand front
You will only see me when I want

> Face it or not, you will still feel the fear when it comes;

Go there or no-where
I can be there beside with no distance

> It comes at any moment and any place

I don't have ticket

> Fear just comes, doesn't need a ticket

I can't make chitchat
But once you know what I am
You don't want to meet me again.

> You don't have power on it, and when you are feared you don't want to feel it anymore.

### Sorry for bad english. Have a nice day.

I got a second guess:

> it may be a fart. you can hear it only when it blows, and ofc you don't want to meet it again.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Invalidated by OP

Is it

> Death?

It seems to match most of the hints.

Comment: First thing that came to mind for me as well (apart from stepmother) however Jesus met death once and he didn't really seem to mind the second time.. Or so I've heard.

Comment: @DrunkWolf Why Jesus? Why not a common man?

Comment: I was simply saying that while i also thought of death as an answer, i have a very hard time placing the last line in that case. Nobody i know (except for Jesus, if fiction counts) ever died twice, and there's no reason to fear death once you're dead.

Comment: Once you are dead, there is no second time. 'Cos if you got another life, death in another life is first time to that life. I also agree with @drunkWolf. This is not yet a correct answer. : )